# Brother Bpac SDK - Access violation with .NET core and .NET 5, but not .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, brother-bpac

I'm using [Brothers bpac](https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/dev/en/bpac/download/index.html?c=eu_ot&lang=en&navi=offall&comple=on&redirect=on) SDK to control a label printer, and I've found that it only works in .NET framework. Using .NET core or .NET 5 gives the exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'. No exception is thrown, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Moving to .NET framework isn't an issue, but I'd like to understand why. Its my understanding that .NET 5 is a sort of successor to .NET core and framework, so I'm interested to know what might possibly be the issue here.

Sorry if this isn't a lot of information to go on, but if anyone has had similar issues with this SDK or any other libraries, any insight on where to investigate would be great!

Comment: Most likely the Brother SDK is trash, like all software produced by printer manufacturers.

Comment: Came here searching for a solution to the same problem, except that we get this error with .Net 4.5.2. Were you able to get past it at all?

Comment: @Apeksha Unfortunately not, the best we could do was move to .NET framework.